# Conversion of text to unicode strings

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, text

I have to process JSON files that looks like this:

```
\u0432\u043b\u0430\u0434\u043e\u043c <b>\u043f\u0443\u0442\u0438\u043c<\/b> \u043d\u0430\u0447
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how this encoding is called.

I would like to convert it to .NET Unicode strings. What's the easies way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Unicode characters for Russian alphabet.
try simply put this line in VisualStudio and it will parse it.

```
string unicodeString = "\u0432\u043b\u0430\u0434\u043e\u043c";
```

Or if you want to convert this string to another encoding, for example utf8, try this code:

```
static void Main()
    {
        string unicodeString = "\u0432\u043b\u0430\u0434\u043e\u043c <b>\u043f\u0443\u0442\u0438\u043c<\b> \u043d\u0430\u0447";
        // Create two different encodings.
        Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

        // Convert the string into a byte[].
        byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

        // Perform the conversion from one encoding to the other.
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, utf8, unicodeBytes);

        // Convert the new byte[] into a char[] and then into a string.
        // This is a slightly different approach to converting to illustrate
        // the use of GetCharCount/GetChars.
        char[] asciiChars = new char[utf8.GetCharCount(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length)];
        utf8.GetChars(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
        string asciiString = new string(asciiChars);

        // Display the strings created before and after the conversion.
        Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", unicodeString);
        Console.WriteLine("Ascii converted string: {0}", asciiString);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

code taken from [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28VS.71%29.aspx)